# How to Keep Data while sliding Android Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 3 fragments : **Page1 - Page 2 - Page3 :**
when i slide to Page3 fragment i lose what i defined for some textviews in Page 1.
and vice versa for Page1, the only one which doesn't change is Page2 (it is in the middle).

**I want to know how can i save data when i slide Fragments.**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put in some code in your `onPause` method to save your data to a DB, a file or SharedPreferences and then put code in the `onResume` method to retrieve that data.

Comment: I'm looking for a clean, solution or some configuration to change

Comment: I used onResume, but there is one problem. onResume of Page1 is Fired when i slide fragments from 3 to 2.

Comment: I'm unclear why that would be an issue... aren't you merely grabbing data there?

Comment: Yes, i grab data from an API and i'm using a progressDialog.
this is the problem, the dialog of Page1 is showed in the Page2.